# Dynamic Custom Options; data in orders with out normal custom options feilds

Tags: orders, cart, custom-options, invoice

The need is that I have a guest count on a product ***(product A)*** that changes the qty of the ordered amount.  What I have done is set up a bunch of custom options for the questions based on the guest for that particular product programmatically when the product  ***(product A)*** is added to the cart.

Currently it is saving the options to the product ***(product A)*** and this is working, but there has to be a better way. Here is what I want to do better on.  As you add a guest there are a set of questions for that guest of the product.  So as I add an order, this product ***(product A)*** get a custom option `guest_1_menu=>'some text'` is saved to the product ***(product A)***  and you can see this new option on the back when editing the product ***(product A)*** .  Now when I make another order the product  ***(product A)*** this time was added to the cart with 2 guests which have there options, so `guest_1_menu=>'some text new value'` and `guest_2_menu=>'some text'`.  Now when you go to look at the product in the back end you have 2 custom options.

This all works like I said, but lets say over many order someone get to 10 guests when they check out, that product ***(product A)*** would have 10 custom options.  Here is a more visual representation of what I'm doing now

```
Order #0001
***(product A)***
    \___ guest 1
            \___ menu
             \___ gift
```

The product on the back now has 2 custom options,

```
- guest_1_menu
- guest_1_gift
```

Now we take a second order

```
Order #0002
***(product A)***
    \___ guest 1
            \___ menu
             \___ gift
    \___ guest 2
            \___ menu
             \___ gift
```

The product on the back now has 4 custom options,

```
- guest_1_menu
- guest_1_gift
- guest_2_menu
- guest_2_gift
```

Now we take a third order

```
Order #0003
***(product A)***
    \___ guest 1
            \___ menu
             \___ gift
    \___ guest 2
            \___ menu
             \___ gift
    \___ guest 3
            \___ menu
             \___ gift
```

The product on the back now has 6 custom options,

```
- guest_1_menu
- guest_1_gift
- guest_2_menu
- guest_2_gift
- guest_3_menu
- guest_3_gift
```

So just to be clear, if the number of custom options are a high water mark basically. (one last order example)

```
Order #0004
***(product A)***
    \___ guest 1
            \___ menu
             \___ gift
```

The product on the back still has 6 custom options as order 3 pushed it up there,

```
- guest_1_menu
- guest_1_gift
- guest_2_menu
- guest_2_gift
- guest_3_menu
- guest_3_gift
```

SO again this works, but you can see how messy this gets, so is there a better way to attach data to an order that will show from cart to invoice?  Happy to add classes or blocks that will help, but I really don't want to have it something that can get edited from the product in the admin.  I hope this was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the custom options to the Quote Item and not to the product. 
Check this method:

```
\Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::addOption
```

It will be shown on the cart if you add it with the array code: additional_options

But you need to make sure that you are not overwriting the options that are already there.
Check this answer from Vinai on how to add options to the quote item and persist them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496266

Comment: And that will show in the cart?

Comment: Edited my answer please check